# Functions: Calculating velocity, time, distance (double type variables)

Tags: c#

I have created a program that wehn the calculate button is pressed, an average speed will be calculated using the total distance travled and the total hours traveled, and that will be multiplied by the time to get from NY city to MIAMI to get the distance from NY city to MIAMI. After button click `Label1` will report the speed, the time and distance and `Clear_textBox()` will clear all textbox fields. The problem is that I am not getting any results back but errors.

Can some one give me guidance in changes to be made in my code?

the functions I am receiving an error `Display_Results` and property `private double get_Time`

```
   namespace form1
   {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private double Calculate_Velocity()
    {
        //Calculate Velocity
        int startingMileageBox;
        startingMileageBox = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

        int endingMileageBox;
        endingMileageBox = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

        double time = Get_Time(); //assuming you have set up GetTime()
        double distance = endingMileageBox - startingMileageBox;
        return distance / time; 
    }

   public double Get_Time()
    {
        //Get Time
        return get_Time;
    }

    private double Calculate_Distance(double velocity, double time)
    {
        //Calculate Distance
        return velocity * time;
    }

    private void Display_Results(double velocity, double time, double distance)
    {
        //Display Results
        label1.Text = "Velocity = " + velocity.ToString() + " time= " + time.ToString() + " Distance = " + distance.ToString();
    }

    private void Clear_Textboxes()
    {
        //Clear textboxes
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
    }



    // Property to GetTime
    private double get_Time
    {


        get
        {



            // variable to hold time
            double time = double.MinValue;

            // Safely parse the text into a double
            if (double.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out time))
            {
                return time;
            }

            // Could just as easily return time here   
            return double.MinValue;
        }
        set
        {
            // Set tbTime
            textBox3.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close(); 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double v = Calculate_Velocity();
        double t = Get_Time();

        double d = Calculate_Distance(v, t);
        Display_Results(v, t, d);

        Clear_Textboxes();

    }
}
```

}

**Form**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Error is in this function

```
private double Display_Results(double velocity, double time, double distance)
            {
                //Display Results
                label1.Text = time + velocity + distance;
            }
```

please convert time +velocity+distance value in string format.

Try following

```
private double Display_Results(double velocity, double time, double distance)
            {
                //Display Results
                double v=-velocity;
                double t=-time;
                double d=-distance;

                label1.Text = (t + v + d).ToString();
            }
```

Comment: +1 yes, thank you. Now i am getting this error for that function: `not all code paths return a value`

Comment: @freelancer Thank you, that fixed the problem, One last issue I am confronting: `private double get_Time` is giving an error for tbTime not being declared. I am trying to grab the value of textBox3 and convert that an int to calculate the rest.

Comment: please try to write if(tbTime.Text==""){tbTime.Text="0"} and let me know the result. I think real problem is there.

Comment: alright, I figured what I wanted to do which is grab the value of textBox3 and then convert to double so I just changed it to `textBox3.Text`. Back to the label issue: Is adding now the results: I want to display them Individually velocity, time and distance

Comment: for that>>>label1.Text="Velocity = "+velocity.Tostring()+" time= "+time.Tostring()+ " Distance = "+ distance.Tostring();  add this in private double Display_Results(double velocity, double time, double distance) function...

Comment: I don't understand why you guys stick to keeping `double` as the return type of `Display_Results` when it obviously doesn't return anything.

Comment: ohh. Guillaume is right. i forgot its void now after updations.

Comment: @Guillaume i have changed to `void` instead of `double`

Comment: @charliecodex23: abel1.Text="Velocity = "+velocity.Tostring()+" time= "+time.Tostring()+ " Distance = "+ distance.Tostring();...has worked or not????

Comment: @freelancer yes that worked. I have updated the code in my question to the actual changes. But Now I am just getting negative results for velocity and distance.

Comment: @freelance yes, the negative sign is the problem

Comment: One last thing: for the `get_time` function instead of giving me minutes, how can i return the data in hours format?

Comment: hehehe...simple...just divide time (variable t) by 60 ...answer wil be in hours